# How to receive score from NSUserDefaults Cocos2d 3.0

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, nsuserdefaults

[image]Im trying to receive my high score using  NSUserDefaults

This is my code for the string receiving it but an error comes up

```
int savedScore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"score_key"];
highScoreText = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",savedScore] fontName:@"a2203.ttf" fontSize:21.0f];
highScoreText.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
highScoreText.color = [CCColor blackColor];
highScoreText.position = ccp(0.15f, 0.95f); // Top Right of screen
[self addChild:highScoreText];
```

This is where my code is getting the score information

```
score++;
[scorelabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"score: %d",score]];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:score forKey:@"score_key"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

return YES;
}
```

Thank you for any advice

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks `highScoreLabel` is declared as an int. Try and find where you declare it and change `int highScoreLabel` to `CCLabelTTF highScoreLabel`.

Comment: Im sorry Connor i confused my self, so i fixed the code i had to what you gave me.
The score is being saved as a key "score_key" on another Scene. What Im trying to do is grab the score being saved and placing it into a label, how would i do that? Also the "Hscore" wasnt suppose to be there, it was from a previous code sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Wow i cant believe i didn't realize that. Thank you Connor very much